# Getting TestNGException while running testng.xml

Tags: java, testng

While I'm running the testng.xml file I'm getting TestNGException . I had tried cleaning up the project but it didn't work. Following is the console

```
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot find class in classpath: frontEndPages.ProjectSetup
    at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.loadClass(XmlClass.java:77)
    at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.init(XmlClass.java:69)
    at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.<init>(XmlClass.java:55)
    at org.testng.xml.TestNGContentHandler.startElement(TestNGContentHandler.java:575)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
    at org.testng.xml.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:38)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:16)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:9)
    at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:152)
    at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:233)
    at org.testng.TestNG.parseSuite(TestNG.java:295)
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:348)
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeEverything(TestNG.java:995)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12.initialize(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:22)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:97)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Comment: Please Check the spelling of your package "frontEndPages"  and class name "ProjectSetup"

Comment: I checked it but I think the problem is with the compilation with java on my pc

Comment: If you are using maven, Remove Dependency and clean maven test. Else, you can re-add testng Jar. There are many ways to rebuild setup. Error defines it.

Comment: @IshitaShah I tried cleaning the project as well as removing the dependencies and adding dependencies in .xml file as well as reinstalling testNG plugin in the eclipse but it is not working on my pc but it is working on other person's pc

Comment: Can you show ProjectSetup?